# WPF and C# multi-step animation (motion+colour change)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, colors, motion

I am trying to do an animation in WPF using C# which moves a rectangle up in my canvas by 100, then I want it to change colour to green once it has moved up by 100 and then moves down to the starting position. However, when I run my code I only see the rectangle moving down (which is the last call) and it's already green. I am not sure how to do this multi-step animation, any help would be very much appreciated! I attach my code:

- XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="question.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:question"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="grid"
          Background="Gray">
        <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas">
            <Rectangle
                x:Name="rect"
                Width="136"
                Height="149"
                Stroke="White" 
                StrokeThickness="3"
                RadiusX="20" 
                RadiusY="20" 
                Canvas.Left="332" 
                Canvas.Top="143"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

- C# file (code behind):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace question
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            moveUp(rect);
            changeColor(rect);
            moveDown(rect);
        }

        public void moveUp(FrameworkElement target)
        {
            var moveUp = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = Canvas.GetTop(target),
                By = -100,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            };
            target.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, moveUp);
        }

        public void moveDown(FrameworkElement target)
        {
            var moveDown = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = Canvas.GetTop(target),
                By = -100,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            };
            target.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, moveDown);
        }

        public void changeColor(FrameworkElement target)
        {
            rect.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

As a summary I want the rectangle to move up while being white. Once it gets up I want it to turn green. Once it turns green, I want it to get back to original position.

I am trying to move rectangle up, once it is up and has stopped to change its colour to green and then move back down. At the moment my animation only moves down and the rectangle is already green while moving.

Comment: You should use a storyboard https://www.codeproject.com/articles/364529/animation-using-storyboards-in-wpf

Comment: Or use the Completed event of the first animation to set the Stroke and start the second animation. Another alternative, set the BeginTime of the second animation.